# Weighted (Perlin?) Noise generation

Tags: c#, game-development, games, noise

Is there a way I can "Weight" a noise generation algorithm to a specific point i.e the center of the generated "image" or one of its corners, assuming the generated "image" is square?

I have been working with Unity5 for around a month, but recently got interested in Noise Generation and Procedural Terrains, which lead me to Perlin Noise, which has lead me to using noise generation for the heightmap of the terrain.

I have implemented Perlin Noise which works fine, however the two versions implemented give different effects:

1. Each tile shares an entire heightmap cut into sections
2. Each tile has its own heightmap

1 - When the entire heightmap is shared, you get an unexpected end to the terrain, which in extreme cases might be 300m up a mountain. eg:
[image: Shared Heightmap]
[image: Seperated Terrain Pieces sharing a single heightmap]

2 - When each tile has an individual heightmap, the ability to get a much more "organic" feel is possible, however it is nearly impossible to achieve an "island" effect with the blending, I end up with some tiles at huge heights and some at the lowest points, however the lowest points might actually be in the center of the map eg:

[image: Seperate Heightmap per Tile]
[image: Seperate Heightmap per Tile]

This is remedied by taking the overall dimensions of a tile (512x513x512 - WxHxD) and taking a sampled point and interpolating the heightmap values between the two neighbouring tiles, in this case the value is 1/3rd of the width = 171 eg:
[image: Sampled blending]

I want to Weight the noise to the center of a square thus giving an "island" effect on the generated heightmap - for example, this image represents how the terrain currently looks from the side (sorry for SumoPaint..):
 - Top is current generation where you can get a peak anywhere on the map, which is annoying
 - Bottom is how I would like the generation to work, having greater weighted peaks in the middle of the terrain with the edges feathering out to near flat where the water would be.

[image: Badly Drawn representation]

If anyone could point me in the correct direction for weighting noise generation, I would be extremely greatful!

Comment: I believe this is on-topic here, but [gamedev SE has a tag specifically for perlin noise questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perlin-noise), so you may want to check that out too.

Comment: @Ixrec when referring another site, it is often helpful to remind that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: While we're fine with hosting this here, if you feel that it is better suited to Game Dev, flag for migration.